# Java left-aligned text and right-aligned numbers in same output line

Tags: java

I am trying to right-align the numbers while keeping the text left-aligned.

```
  //Display the test average and grade 
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
     (String.format("Initial Cost: $%,.2f\nDiscount: $%,.2f\n" +
     "Final Cost: $%,.2f", initialCost, discount, finalCost)));
```

How do I display the lines with the decimals aligned?

Comment: To align it like that you'll need to know exactly how long each number is, and pad lines with correct number of spaces (assuming your message dialog font is monospace, otherwise it's even harder).

Comment: Since no look-and-feel uses a monospaced font by default (as far as I know), you will have to pass a JPanel which uses a GridBagLayout and which contains each name in its own JLabel and each monetary amount in its own JLabel.  Yes, you can pass a JPanel instead of a String as a JOptionPane message argument.

Comment: Can you tell me where in the code I would pad the lines with the correct number of spaces, say 20?